# What is the best usage of columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, integer, left-join

I got one table called Table1, it has around 20 columns. Half of these columns are string values, and the rest are integer. My question is so simple: what's better, have all the columns into only one table, or have it distributed into 2, 3 or even 4 tables? If so, I'd have to join them using LEFT JOIN.

What's the best choice?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to split up your data like that?  Unless the column doesn't make sense to be on that table, leave it there.

Answer (score 1):

The question of "best" depends on how the table is being used.  So, there is no real answer to the question.  I can say that 20 columns is not a lot and many very reasonable tables have more than 20 columns of mixed types.

First observation:  If you are asking such a question, you have some knowledge of SQL but not in-depth knowledge.  One table is almost certainly the way to go.

What might change this advice?  If many of the *integer* columns are `NULL` -- say 90% of the records have all of them as `NULL` -- then those `NULL` values are probably just wasting space on the data page.  By eliminating those rows and storing the values in another table, you would reduce the size of the data.

The same is true of the string values, but with a caveat.  Whereas the integers occupy at least 4 bytes, variable length strings might be even smaller (depends on the exact way that the database stores them).

Another reason would be on how the data is typically used.  If the queries are usually using just a handful of columns, then storing each column in a separate table could be beneficial.  To be honest, the overhead of the key column generally overwhelms any savings.  And, such a data structure is really lousy for updates, inserts, and deletes.

However, this becomes quite practical in a columnar database such as Paraccel, Amazon Redshift, or Vertica.  Such databases have built-in support for this type of splitting and it can have some very remarkable effects on performance.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this with an example for `users` table -

```
1) `users` - id, name, dob, city, zipcode etc.
2) `users_products` - id, user_id(FK), product_name, product_validity,...
3) `users_billing_details` - id, user_id(FK to `users`), billing_name, billing_address..
4) `users_friends` - id, user_id(FK to `users`), friend_id(FK to same table `users`)
```

Hence if have many relations, use MANY-to-MANY relationship. If few relationship go with using the same table. All depends upon your structure and requirements.

**SUGGESTION** - Many-to-Many makes your data structure more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 20 columns in 1 table. Nothing wrong with that. But then are you sure you are designing the structure properly?

Could some of these data change significantly in the future?

Is the table trying to encapsulate a single activity or entity?

Does the table have a singular meaning with respect to the domain or does it encapsulate multiple entities?

Could the structure be simplified into smaller tables having singular meaning for each table and then "Relationships" added via primary key/foreign keys?

These are some of the questions you take into consideration while designing a database.

If you find answer to these questions, you will know yourself whether you should have a single table or multiple tables?